# Get an error when getting data from the server in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I have an `AchievementResponse` model with a `fromJson` method. I receive data from the server and I want to place this data in a list of type `AchievementResponse`. But when I get the data and add it to the list, I get the error `_TypeError (type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')`. If I add the `toString()` method, I also get an error (screenshots below). Tell me how to fix the error?

**model**

```
  factory AchievementResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AchievementResponse(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      status: json['status'],
    );
  }
```

**response**

```
Future<List<AchievementResponse>?> getInfo
...
if (response is dio.Response) {
  final data = response.data;
  print(data['achievementsProgress']);

  return jsonDecode(data['achievementsProgress'].toString())
      .map(AchievementResponse.fromJson)
      .toList();
```

[image]

**error**

### [image]

**error withou toString() method**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `jsonDecode` on `data['achievementsProgress']`, it's already decoded.

Looking at the exception, it seems `data['achievementsProgress']` is a map with a `data` list in it. Try this:

```
return data['achievementsProgress']['data']
    .map(AchievementResponse.fromJson)
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change code of return

```
  List<AchievementResponse> achievementResponse = AchievementResponse.fromJson(response.data);
        
  return achievementResponse;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you pay attention to your error, you will see the data that you are getting from your server is `Map<String, dynamic>` but you are decoding the response as `String`. anyway to fix this problem you can pass `achievementsProgress` map to  `fromJson` witout any converting to `String`:

```
Future<List<AchievementResponse>?> getInfo() async {
  final response = await _dio.get(url);

  if (response is dio.Response) {
    final data = response.data;
    final List<dynamic> achievementsProgress = data['achievementsProgress'];

    return achievementsProgress
        .map((achievement) => AchievementResponse.fromJson(achievement))
        .toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('failed in loading data');
  }
}
```

happy coding...